# NodeJS process is hanging after processing a large number of records

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a node JS process with the following code snippet. I am trying to cache 450k transactions in memory (transactionObj).

```
 const transactionObj = {};
    const transactionCursor = target_db.collection("transaction").find();
     processTxns = 0; 
    for await (const transactionDoc of transactionCursor) {
      processTxns++;
      if (transactionDoc.orderId && transactionDoc.orderId[0]) {
        const orderIdString = String(transactionDoc.orderId[0].oid);
        if (!orderIdString) continue;
        const existingDoc = transactionObj[orderIdString];
        if (!existingDoc || existingDoc._id < transactionDoc._id) {
          transactionObj[orderIdString] = transactionDoc;
        }
      }
      console.log("Process Txns: "+processTxns)
    }
```

When I am executing this code the process hangs after processing a certain number of records something around 16K or 20k different every time.
I tried using Map but the same behavior. I also tried passing the argument

```
node --max-old-space-size=6144
```

but the issue still remains. This code is running on a Windows server with 32GB of RAM. I don't see a lot of memory usage while the code is running (less than 50%)

Comment: put mongodb tag this post.

Answer (score 0):

If those operations are memory intensive you should process them in chunks, one option is to implement pagination in your query and get a limited number of transactions and process it.

```js
const CHUNK_SIZE = 10;

async function* readChunksFromDB() {
  const numberOfTransactions = await target_db
    .collection("transaction")
    .count();
  const numberOfChunks = Math.ceil(numberOfTransactions / CHUNK_SIZE);

  for (let i = 0; i < numberOfChunks; i++) {
    const chunk = await target_db
      .collection("transaction")
      .find({ take: CHUNK_SIZE, skip: i * CHUNK_SIZE });

    yield chunk;
  }
}

async function processChunks() {
  const transactionObj = {};
  processTxns = 0;
  for await (const chunk of readChunksFromDB()) {
    for (const transactionDoc of chunk) {
      processTxns++;
      if (transactionDoc.orderId && transactionDoc.orderId[0]) {
        const orderIdString = String(transactionDoc.orderId[0].oid);
        if (!orderIdString) continue;
        const existingDoc = transactionObj[orderIdString];
        if (!existingDoc || existingDoc._id < transactionDoc._id) {
          transactionObj[orderIdString] = transactionDoc;
        }
      }
      console.log("Process Txns: " + processTxns);
    }
  }
}
```

Or maybe with Streams using pipes that have an automatic backpressure mechanism. Streams are the recommended solution of NodeJS for managing high amount of data of operations:

```js
const { Readable, Transform } = require("stream");

const transactionsStream = Readable.from(readChunksFromDB());
const processTransactionStream = new Transform({
  transform(chunk, encoding, callback) {
    const transactions = JSON.parse(chunk.toString());
    console.log(transactions);
    transactions
      .map((transactionDoc) => {
        if (transactionDoc.orderId && transactionDoc.orderId[0]) {
          const orderIdString = String(transactionDoc.orderId[0].oid);
          if (!orderIdString) {
            return transactionDoc;
          }

          const existingDoc = transactionObj[orderIdString];
          if (!existingDoc || existingDoc._id < transactionDoc._id) {
            transactionObj[orderIdString] = transactionDoc;
          }

          return transactionDoc;
        }
      })
      .forEach((transaction) => {
        console.log(transaction);
        this.push(JSON.stringify(transaction));
      });

    callback();
  },
});

transactionsStream.pipe(processTransactionStream).on("data", (chunk) => {
    console.log(chunk.toString())
});
```

**In both cases, you will have to manage a different array for deduplication but you will gain a lot in terms of performance.**

https://blog.appsignal.com/2022/02/02/use-streams-to-build-high-performing-nodejs-applications.html

Comment: Im m getting this error when in run the above code TypeError: chunk is not iterable

Comment: Did you parse chuck to an `object` from `json`?

Comment: The problem was the find return a cursor and not array, after adding toArray() to the end of it it started working fine

Comment: But the problem of code hanging wasn't really solved